# Desabilitar botão enquanto o form não estiver válido

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Preciso desabilitar um `button` de salvar quando todos os campos estivem validados, o seguinte código o `button` está sempre sendo desabilitado, mais teria como adicionar uma condição para alterar apenas se tiver valido na camada cliente?

```
 $('input[type=submit]').click(function (e) {

        //if ( $('#FormCadastro').valid()) {

            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            $(this).attr('value', 'Salvando');
            $('#btnsalvar').submit();

    });

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DescricaoDaNaoConformidade, new { style = "width: 400px; height:120px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescricaoDaNaoConformidade)
        </div>
  <input  type="submit" value="Salvar E Concluir" name="action:Concluir" />

</form>
```

Comment: Não ficou clara sua questão. Você quer que o botão seja ativado apenas após todos os campos do form estiverem validados?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer que toda vez que algum campo seja alterado ele valide e habilite o botão ou não, correto?

Comment: @RodrigoGomesDias O usuário está clicando as  2 vezes no botão na hora de salvar o que ocasiona em informações duplicadas, quero quando clicar em salvar e os campos estivem validos liberar o botão e quando clicar na primeira vez bloquear o click do botão salvar.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, caso queira realmente fazer dessa forma, você precisa verificar se o `form` está válido a cada interação do usuário. Se possui somente `inputs` em seu formulário, pode utilizar o evento `blur` do jQuery. Pode obter os elementos pelo que desejar, classe, tipo, etc.

Um exemplo simples seria assim:

```js
$('input').blur(function () {
   verificarForm();
});
        
function verificarForm(){
  var valid = $("#MyForm").valid();
 if(valid){
        $('#btnSalvar').prop("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

```css
button:disabled {
    background: red;
}
.invalid {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 

  
<form id="MyForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="" data-required-message="Name is required." class="valid">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="" data-required-message="Email is required." data-type-message="You must provide a valid email address." class="valid"><label for="email" generated="true" class="error" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid email address.</label>
    </div>
    <div>
       <button id="btnSalvar" disabled="disabled">Salvar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Exemplo no [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/9ky8Z/69/)

Lembrando que da forma que eu fiz está verificando somente os `inputs`. Se tiver `textarea`, `checkbox`, `selects`, dentre outros elementos, deverá tratá-los também.
E apenas reforçando, não esqueça do `ModelState.isValid()` em seu controller. Validação somente no cliente é muito perigoso, pois é fácil de ser manipulado.

#### Edição

Para não ter mais de uma requisição e duplicar os dados salvos, você pode verificar se o modelo está válido, se tiver você bloqueia o botão.
Ficaria desta forma:

```js
    $('#btnSalvar').on('click', function (e) {
            var button = $('#btnSalvar');

            button.prop('disabled', true);

            var valid = $("#MyForm").valid();
            console.log(valid);
            if (!valid) {

                e.preventDefault();
                button.prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('#MyForm').submit();
            }
        });
```

```css
button:disabled {
    background: red;
}
.invalid {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 

  
<form id="MyForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="" data-required-message="Name is required." class="valid">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="" data-required-message="Email is required." data-type-message="You must provide a valid email address." class="valid"><label for="email" generated="true" class="error" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid email address.</label>
    </div>
    <div>
       <button id="btnSalvar">Salvar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Fonte: [Disabling a submit button after one click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9378878/4843158)

Comment: Consigo fazer para verificar apenas quando ele clicar no button? Eu conseguir fazer a validação no evento submit contudo o evento não é disparado se o botão é desabilitado após se chamado. Por eu quero bloquear múltiplos clique no mesmo button.

Comment: Para fazer da forma que quer, não poderá desabilitar o botão, ou então terá que fazer uma forma de chamar a validação (para habilitar o botão) antes, deixando assim a validação no `submit` e nos campos. Eu particularmente não vejo necessidade de desabilitar o botão, bloqueando o `form` e obrigado o usuário a preencher corretamente, não há necessidade de mudar o botão.

Comment: meu problema não é fazer o usuário preencher direito e sim bloquear que o usuário faça clique várias vezes no mesmo button. Por isso quero bloquear o button ao ser clicado a primeira vez.

Comment: @Zica Por qual motivo não pode clicar mais de uma vez? Ao clicar mais ele está salvando 2x no banco?

Comment: isso mesmo. Teve caso que salvou duas vezes no banco de dados.

Comment: @Zica Editei a resposta, veja se lhe atende agora.

Comment: ainda não, nesta forma não é feito o bind com o controller do MVC. Quando desabilita o button ele não faz o bind.

Comment: @Zica Não estou alterando o bind do controller. O controller só será chamado se o `form` estiver válido, caso contrário, nada é feito.

Comment: me expressei errado, ele valido o formulário contudo não cai no controller.

Comment: @Zica Foi erro meu. Alterei a resposta, veja se melhorou.

Comment: não funcionou ainda, quando desabilito o button e faço subimit ele não cai no controller.

Comment: @Zica Faltou o `else`. Testei o código aqui e agora está fazendo o que deseja, ou pelo menos o que entendi que é o que você deseja.

Comment: funcionou agora, acho que entendi um problema que eu tenho e relacionado a ter 2 botões com ações diferente para o mesmo formulário estou usando ActionNameSelectorAttribute, neste exemplo ele não manda ação correta por isso não está funcionando pra min.

Comment: @Zica Nesse caso, abra outra pergunta específica com esse problema, que te ajudo lá também